# Uniqueness of solution to ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE system
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) & = a\cdot x(t)y(t) + b \cdot x(t) + c\cdot x(t)^2y(t)z(t)\\
\dot{y}(t) &= -a\cdot x(t)y(t) - c\cdot x(t)^2y(t)z(t) \\
\dot{z}(t) &= d + e\cdot z(t) + f\cdot x(t)z(t) + g\cdot z(t)^2 x(t)^2
\end{align}
together with initial conditions $x(0)=x_0,y(0)=y_0$. There is no initial condition for $z(t)$. Moreover, I know that the system converges to a limit point $(x(\infty),y(\infty),z(\infty))=(0,y_\infty,z_\infty)$, where $y_\infty>0$ is unknown, while $z_\infty<0$ is known; and
$(x(\infty),y(\infty),z(\infty))\neq(x(0),y(0),z(0))$.

I want to know whether (or under which conditions) the system has a unique solution and how this can be established.